# Using shared preferences for persistent login, is that vulnerability?

Tags: android, security

Recently I found many Android apps using shared preferences for persistent login, such app requires user name and password from the user to login for the first time, but from then on requires no additional actions from the user.

In rare cases, that app will store the password in the file like login_account.xml of the shared_prefs folder, once the user rooted his Android phone, other evil app may read this file to get the user's password.

In most cases, I found that the apps will store a login key(not password) in the login_account.xml of the shared_prefs folder, it seems to be secure because the evil app cannot steal the password. But it can still get the login status of the victim because he can replace his login key with the victim's.

I am wondering if there's some way that can both ***protect our users from login key been stolen*** and ***do not requires our users to input his  password to load our app each time***?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358715/authentication-model-for-android-application/7358882#7358882

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Devices are inherently unsecure so no matter what you do, there will always be a possibility for "Evil Guy" to do something. There  is absolutely no solution to that.
You can, however, mitigate the risks somewhat by doing what Chirag Raval suggests : only store the login and the fact that it was successful.
I would add to that to only 'auto'-login for a limited time and then show the login dialog again to reconfirm the password.

You can make it a little more secure by generating a signature of your phone, sending it upon the first login and have the server send a response string which you can use to login subsequently. It would be somewhat secure by the fact that it would be very hard to guess , it would not work on another phone and it still requires the password. To generate such a signature, I would concatenate lots of field values from the Build class, the phone's id and possibly values obtained in TelephonyManager (home network), then generate a digest from that. The most secure way to do it is to use an SHA-1 HMAC (look at the Bouncy castle library).

Of course, this all breaks down against a dedicated adversary : he can attach a debugger to your app, trace all its calls and figure out the algorithm for the signature. That's because the device is unsecure as I wrote at the top. (PS: this actually happened to me while a client was testing the security of an app).

Answer (score 2):

so the SharedPreferences, if configured properly in private mode

Example:

```
    SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Should be enough to protect your data since only your app is supposed to have access to that information.

Android doesn't have more advanced security measures that I know of (I think I read somewhere that Android 4.0 had new ones but if you want you app to be used by most people, you can't use that at the moment) and encryption is useless since you need a key and if that key is stored in your mobile device then it can also be stolen.

What you can do is: Tell people not to Root their Android phones and if the phones are stolen then just change the password from an other place. Rooting your cellphone increases security threats and voids any "security" that Android puts in place, hence if you do it, you expose yourself to data theft and therefore, it should only be done if you are willing to risk it and really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

> There is one simple way . First time just ask username and password
>   from user, if login is correct then only store the true flag in shared
>   preference . So next time you just check the flag and you know weather
>   the user is already logged in or not .
>
> So this way no one can steal user password.

Comment: But if I change the user name to other users in login_account.xml, and modify the flag to true. Is that means I can get the login status of the other user?

Comment: why? Without such things like login key, what shall the app to verify a user?

Comment: as bitbox suggest there is absolutely no solution to that.